# Error al intentar obtener numero de contacto de la agenda

Tags: android, android-permissions

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para enviar mensajes en los dos primeros campos quiero que se muestren el nombre del contacto y el numero del contacto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el nombre ya lo he podido capturar, pero al procesar el número me muestra el siguiente error, ya he asignado los permisos en el manifest.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que use para obtener los datos de contacto

```
 private void renderContact(Uri uri){

    EditText edtNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNombre);
    EditText edtNumTel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNumTel);

    edtNombre.setText(getName(uri));
    edtNumTel.setText(getPhone(uri));
}

private String getName(Uri uri){
    String name = null;

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Cursor c = contentResolver.query(
            uri,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
            null,
            null,
            null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        name = c.getString(0);
    }

    c.close();

    return name;
}

private String getPhone(Uri uri){
    String id = null;
    String phone = null;

    Cursor contacCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            uri,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
            null,
            null,
            null);
    if (contacCursor.moveToFirst()){
        id = contacCursor.getString(0);
    }
    contacCursor.close();

    String selectionArgs = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE+"= " +
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;

    Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
            selectionArgs,
            new String[]{id},
            null);
    if (phoneCursor.moveToFirst()){
        phone = phoneCursor.getString(0);
    }
    phoneCursor.close();

    return phone;
}
```

ERROR!

```
07-07 12:00:40.211 3891-3891/com.alexiscaballero.appdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.alexiscaballero.appdemo, PID: 3891
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/2522i6ea09ce78ba13648.3789r131-292B393529393F4335/131 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.alexiscaballero.appdemo/com.alexiscaballero.appdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=3891, uid=10105 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4120)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4163)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6208)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=3891, uid=10105 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
                                                                           at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                                           at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                                           at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
                                                                           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:534)
                                                                           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
                                                                           at com.alexiscaballero.appdemo.MainActivity.getPhone(MainActivity.java:178)
                                                                           at com.alexiscaballero.appdemo.MainActivity.renderContact(MainActivity.java:136)
                                                                           at com.alexiscaballero.appdemo.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:125)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6937)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4116)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4163) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6208) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

Comment: si lees tu error, esta en una consulta que haces en sqlite, hay una linea que dice >Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ANDdata2": sy....

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda compañero, pero las únicas consultas que hago son las que están en los métodos

Comment: Tendrá algo que ver que la versión de android es 6.0?

Comment: es que probé con android 4.2 y si funciono sin problemas pero ya probando en versiones superiores me genera ese error

Comment: tendrías que revisar en la documentación oficial de android, algún permiso ya no debe ser compatible, desconozco cual podría ser tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero y es lo que hago porque creo que si va a ser algo de compatibilidad de permisos entre versiones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que para Android 6.0 cambiaron los permisos y ahora ademas de agregar los permisos en el manifest tienes que preguntar en tiempo de ejecución si los permisos están concedidos (Con todos menos el de Internet pasa esto).

Para preguntar si tienes el permiso de contactos tendrías que hacer esto:

```
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //SOLICITAR PERMISO
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 123);
        }else{
            //CONCEDIDO
            renderContact(uri);
        }
```

y sobre escribir este método para tomar el resultado:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case 123:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                renderContact(uri);
            }else{
                //NEGADO
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Nota que el segundo parámetro del `requestPermissions` es un id para que puedas identificar la solicitud, normalmente se hace una constante para evitar bugs.

espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Si era eso, ya lo había resuelto desde hace un rato pero muchas gracias por la aportación compañero :)